# Optimal way to handle current / previous values

Tags: c#

I'm working a small project on my free time but I'm not happy with the way I handle current / previous "values" (In my case, values is a class)

To describe shortly what my topic is about is that I've a grid which contains a list of cells. When I hover or click a cell, I paint the cell accordingly. But of course, when I'm no longuer hovering a cell or select another cell, I need to paint the new cell and paint the previous one as it originally was.

So far I came to this :

```
public class PreviousCurrent<T> where T : class
{
   T current;

   public T Previous { get; set; }

   public T Current
   {
        get => current;
        set
        {
            if(value == current)
                return;

            if (Previous != null)
            {
                Previous = current;
                current = value;
            }
            else
                current = value;
        }
    }

    internal PreviousCurrent(T previous, T current)
    {
        Previous = previous;
        Current = current;
    }

    public static PreviousCurrent<T> Empty => new PreviousCurrent<T>(null, null); 
}
```

It works, but I was wondering if there is a more simple / elegant way to handle such situation ?

Any constructive help / criticism is welcome !

Thanks for your advices !

Comment: Typically one would implement something like this in a method and not a property, as it isn't immediately obvious that using the setter property on `Current` will change the value in `Previous`.

Other than that nothing strikes me as strange, although it might be simple to just use a stack instead of writing your own datastructure. You could use a list or array or any other datastructure, it's just this is what stacks are designed for.

Comment: This question seems better suited for http://codereview.stackexchange.com

Comment: The name could use some work. `Previous` and `Current` are properties of *what*? The *what* should be the class name. I don't love `StatefulItem` but think it's better. :)

Comment: It feels odd to me that `Previous` has a public setter. Doesn't that break the functionality?

Comment: Thanks for your replies and sorry if I didn't post in the correct category. @Ben because my component is a grid so I need to handle previous hovered cell, selected etc and refresh and re-instate them as they originally were. I was considering a small 2 length array to store the data.

Comment: @Rufus, yes Previous can have a protected setter of course, still works without breaking anything. The only propose of the generic class is to store previous and current a class, since T is a class in the code I pasted.

Answer (score 0):

in common way you need `Momento` pattern. you can find some implementation [like this](https://refactoring.guru/design-patterns/memento/csharp/example)

i think you should takecare about these details

1. do you need store more then one state?
2. should it be thread safe? maybe you need ConcurrentStack or just lock()
3. do you store mutable state? maybe you need deep copy

in simple case you can reduce it to class with variable as in your code

Comment: Thanks. I didn't know about the Momento pattern but it's sure is interesting one. In my case, it seems to be a bit "too much" (just like the code I pasted).  Basically. I want to paint differently if a cell is being hovered or clicked. So, it's only about user inputs with mouse.

Comment: 1/ I need a second state to restore the painting (eg, mouse is hovering another cell, I need to draw it normally and the new one with the hovered color). Also I don't want the "Cell" class to have properties like "IsHovered / IsSelected" (which are exclusive) and make some LINQ query looping through all cells to set the property to false and draw the cell. 2/ yes, it's thread safe 3/ Yes, I may need a deep copy since the cells can have some properties updated in the meanwhile - even though not likely because the state changes with mouse, but the properties are depending of the keyboard.